# Automatically fill database with a users related model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just started learning ruby on rails and my first application is an office file tracking system which has 4 models

1. Office model which has_many users
2. User model(devise) which belongs_to office
3. File model which has_many trackers
4. Tracker model which belongs_to file and belongs_to user

i have been able to setup the relationship between tracker and user as follows:

tracker model

```
class Tracker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :nasfile
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User' 
  belongs_to :receiver, :foreign_key => :receiver_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable,:recoverable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :authentication_keys => [:username], password_length: 6..25

  belongs_to :office
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :office

  has_many :sent_files,:class_name => 'Tracker', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_files,:class_name => 'Tracker', :foreign_key => 'recepient_id'

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end

end
```

office model

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department

  has_many :users
end
```

Auto filling user who is sending the file in my create action in tracker controller

```
def create
    @tracker = Tracker.new(tracker_params)

    @tracker.sender_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tracker.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tracker, notice: 'Tracker was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tracker }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tracker.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And Displaying it in my index view

```
<tbody>
    <% @trackers.each do |tracker| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= tracker.nasfile %></td>
        <td><%= tracker.sender.username if tracker.sender.present? %></td>
        <td><%= tracker.receiver_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', tracker %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tracker_path(tracker) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', tracker, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

The main problem i have now is,i am confused on how to setup the relationship between the tracker and the office the user belongs to so as to automatically fill in the current_users office and that's the main essence of the app because a file moves between offices but i want a user to always be attached to a file for integrity sake in case a file gets missing, there will be someone to hold responsible.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your post with relationships from each model (not just tracker)?  Once your relationships are set up properly, you should have accessors you can use to refer to all related entities (e.g. `User.office`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if I am not understanding the problem, but it seems like you are just trying to figure out how to connect the `Tracker` to the `Office` of the `current_user` who is saved as the sender on the `Tracker`.

If this is the case, the `Tracker` doesn't need to store any information about a `User`'s `Office`, it only needs to track the `User` itself. You can then reference the `Office` as steve klein suggested, through the `Tracker`.

```
@tracker.sender.office
```

or

```
@tracker.sender.office.name
```

or even better yet (if you delegate the name to office):

```
@tracker.sender.office_name 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise...
    ...
    delegate :name, to: :office, prefix: true
end
```

This will get you the name of the office (if `.name` exists). As long as the `User` has an associated `Office` record, this will get you what you need.

Comment: Thanks alot, i tried that before but it kept giving me errors, i didn't know the problem was from my schema, somehow it got messed up but after checking your answer, i dropped my database and reran all migrations and it worked. I've cracking my brains for hours now, Thanks once more. Sorry couldn't upvote, Just joined about 2hrs ago

Comment: Not a problem and thanks for selecting this as an answer! Good luck and let me know if you have any questions in the future.

Comment: I've gotten everything to work but i would like to add a file status field to tracker, which will default to in-transit when a sender sends the file until the receiver logs-in to verify that he is in possession of the file, then the status changes to received. How do i have a notification appear when the receiver logs in with a button to accept and when he clicks it the status automatically changes. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I humbly suggest that the base problem is that your data isn't normalized. You should use a has_many through relationship for trackers to users.

Something like this:

```
class Tracker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_trackers
  has_many :users, through => :user_trackers, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_trackers
end

class UserTracker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tracker
  belongs_to :tracker_type
end

class TrackerType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_trackers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_trackers
  has_many :trackers, through => :user_trackers, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_trackers
end
```

The join table, UserTracker, has user_id, tracker_id and tracker_type_id fields. You can add a file_id as well, if that is part of the relationship. The nature of the relationship between models is stored inside the join table, which can have as much information as you want about that relationship. Build nested forms to create the relationships auto-magically using the accepts_nested_attributes_for. TrackType holds the 'sender' and 'receiver' values.

There is are several tutorials and railscasts on using information this way. I just went through setting it up for an application I am using and it works very well once you get it all set up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but im still a bit confused. In the TrackType model, shouldnt it be has_many :user_trackers. Secondly why is there a TrackType model and lastly can u give me an idea how the UserTracker table should look like to include the users office.

Comment: Corrected.  The TrackType is storing the information that you were putting in the original "Tracker" by calling the users "sender" and "receiver". For example, if you have a new user type of "cc" or "bcc" or "reviewer", in your method you would need to add additional fields to the trackers table. In the way I outlined, you will only need to add additional records to the "TrackType" table. Whether a user is a "sender" or a "receiver" is stored in the join table using the track_type_id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i got it to work as it is but i'll also try your way on a new git branch.It will be a way to learn has_many through relationships.Its still kinda confuses me.Sorry couldn't up vote, not enough points. Thanks alot